# Getting 401 error with UploadSession with Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, daemon, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use a daemon app to upload a large file to a user's OneDrive for Business account.  I have managed to authenticate and get a bearer token, create folders and upload small files.

For large files, I create an upload session and receive an error when trying to add a file part using that session.  I have included my fiddler traces to try diagnose this.  I have removed my sensitive information.

I request an upload session

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/drive/items/{folder id}:/Test.csv:/createUploadSession HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {bearer token}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 0
```

I receive a response with the following content:

```
"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.uploadSession",
"expirationDateTime":"2016-10-05T11:39:29.5104044Z",
"nextExpectedRanges":["0-"],
"uploadUrl":"https://{my tenant name}.sharepoint.com/personal/name_domain_co_za/_api/v2.0/drive/root:/Backups/Test:/uploadSession?guid='aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'&path='~tmp12_Test.csv'&overwrite=True&rename=False"}
```

Then I try PUT to that upload url

```
PUT https://{my tenant name}.sharepoint.com/personal/name_domain_co_za/_api/v2.0/drive/root:/Backups/Test:/uploadSession?guid='aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'&path='~tmp12_Test.csv'&overwrite=True&rename=False HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer {bearer token}
Content-Range: bytes 0-327679/16333102
Host: {my tenant name}.sharepoint.com
Content-Length: 327680
Expect: 100-continue
```

Then the response contains the following relevant lines.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"

{"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}
```

I find it very odd because with the current application configuration, I can upload a small file to the same path successfully so, unless I'm misunderstanding something, there shouldn't be anything wrong with permissions.

Comment: There is a thread on [github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/495#issuecomment-253028580) for the same issue. When there is a resolution there, I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:*
The actual issue was that the request was attempting to use an app-only token to authenticate with OneDrive for Business through the Graph. Unfortunately this scenario is not currently supported, and while some scenarios may work there are a number that do not (such as this one). While we cannot comment on timelines it's definitely on our radar!

*Original:*
There are a couple of things that factor in to uploading fragments to a OneDrive for Business account via Graph.

1. The authentication tokens are NOT compatible. Said another way, the bearer token you use to call `createUploadSession` on graph CANNOT be used for the `PUT` requests that directly hit the OneDrive for Business endpoint. This is primarily because the tokens are bound to specific audiences - a token for `https://graph.microsoft.com/` will not work on `https://{my tenant name}.sharepoint.com/`.
2. Due to #1, the `uploadUrl` returned should NOT actually require auth in the first place - we don't want developers to juggle multiple auth tokens for the different endpoints.

It seems like #2 is where things aren't quite right in repro you outlined. Can you confirm that the `uploadUrl` values you're receiving do NOT contain `access_token` or `prooftoken` query parameters? If that's the case, can you get `request-id` header from the response of the `createUploadSession` call?

Comment: If I don't put any bearer token on the PUT request, I get 403 Forbidden.

There is only "guid", "path", "overwrite" and "rename" query string parameters in the uploadUrl.

The request-id for the createUploadSession is 1f7f8c78-ed0d-40ac-9fd0-e6f3c0631989

Comment: Sorry to bounce around like this, but I'm having trouble finding that request. Do you have the time at which the request was made (preferably in UTC) - that'll help correlate.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I made another request now. Fri, 14 Oct 2016 20:47:45 GMT
bdc93a86-84f8-4bed-9d7c-dbd3ce8ba98f

Comment: I glossed over the part where you mentioned you're writing a daemon app - I'm assuming that means you're using an app-only token? The request information seems to confirm that. Unfortunately Graph does not yet support such tokens for OneDrive scenarios :(. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help diagnosing this.  Sorry, I should have put more emphasis on that daemon part.   Pity its not supported yet.  I'll keep trying in the future.

Comment: Hi, i want to do exactly the same as @DarylVanSittert have done. Any news on this?

Comment: app-only / daemon scenarios should be working fine now - if you're having issues feel free to create another question here, or over at [our GitHub page](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-api-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here : uploading small files is performed correctly.

To upload larger files, the beta endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta" is used for achieving an "Upload Session".  This request succeeded.

But when using this "Upload Session" URI, the HTTP PUT command fails :

x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"

This is the C# Code to send the large file :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    byte[] sContents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"<MYLARGEFILE>");
    long length = sContents.Length;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessTokenGraphMicrosoft);
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(sContents);
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length.ToString());
    var response = client.PutAsync(<UPLOADSESSIONURI>, content).Result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  What are you trying to upload to?  Onedrive/Onedrive for Bus./Sharepoint Folder?

Comment: Hi Daryl.  I targetted Onedrive for Business , exactly the same as you and received a Sharepoint URI. :o

I noticed the Office365 implementation did create a temp file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error on uploading the file after creating the upload session. After a lot of trial error, I have worked out I am only getting this when the document name contains a space.

The reason is because the upload url returned in the createUploadSession response is already URL encoded. My REST client was double encoding it, as it presumed that it was not encoded. Once double encoded the upload session could not be found on the server and it returned a 401 with an empty body.